# Is the function bringing everything in A to the smallest element in B an initial segment embedding?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory

In class, we defined initial segment embedding in the following way:

Initial segment embedding is a function $f:A\to B$ $s.t.$ $x\leq y\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)$, and range($f$) is an initial segment of $B$, $i.e.$ let $X=$range($f$), then $\forall y\forall x(x\in X, y\in B,y<x\Longrightarrow y\in X)$.

Here is my question: Let $b_0$ be the smallest element in $B$. Since we know that $\leq$ is reflexive, we have $b_0\leq b_0$. Then is the function $f:A\to B$, $f(x)=b_0$ an initial segment embedding?

Thoughts: I think it is since $x\leq y\Longleftrightarrow f(x)=b_0\leq b_0=f(y)$ and $\{b_0\}$ is the entire range of $f$ and it is clearly an initial segment following the definition.

Thank you!

Comment: It is, but there's one catch — $B$ needs to have a smallest element for this to function! Can you see how to find an 'initial segment embedding' between two ordered sets where $B$ doesn't have a smallest element?

Also, if $B$ _does_ have a smallest element, this isn't just an initial segment embedding, it's the 'minimal' one in a suitable sense. How might you make that formal?

Comment: Thanks! So if we say that $B$ is a well-order then this would work? Is it minimal simply because there is no proper subset (in this case just $\emptyset$) of range($f$) could also be an initial segment?

Comment: Yeah; if $B$ is defined to be well-ordered sets then this absolutely works. (And if $A$ is a well-ordered set then $B$ _must_ be, though the converse isn't necessarily true).

And I was thinking 'minimal' in a partial-order sense; given two initial segment embeddings (and in general, two order-preserving embeddings) $f,g: A\mapsto B$, you can define $f\leq g$ in a pointwise fashion — that is, $f\leq g$ if $f(a)\leq g(a)$ for all $a\in A$. This defines a partial order, and your embedding is minimal for this partial order.

Comment: A total order can also be defined lexicographically: let $a\in A$ be minimal such that $f(a)\neq g(a)$, and define $f\lt g$ if $f(a)\lt g(a)$. Your embedding is the smallest element of this total order.